# Setting Opacity property for Window Image Background

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Window with background image. I want to change image Opacity property from 0 to 1 at button click, and later from 1 to 0, again at button click. I wanted this transition to occur smoothly, that is why I'm using Storyboard.
 
The following will work but animation is an non-ending cycle, so I'm struggling  with stop and resume animation at will. If possibly I want to do this without codebehing support.
Advice?

```
 <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="imgBackground" ImageSource="Resources/Background.png" ></ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>

        <Button Width="75" Height="21" Content="Go">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="imgBackground"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" 
                                             BeginTime="0:0:0" AutoReverse="False" >                                
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753367(v=vs.110).aspx

You probably want a combination of the Duration property and RepeatBehavior property.

Comment: Ok Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="0:0:1"  did the job.